# Cannot import gradle project into Eclipse Photon

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-photon

I have a project that used to load fine into Eclipse Oxygen. Recently, I upgraded my Eclipse to Photon. Since then, I started getting the following error when I try to import a project. Any ideas on how to resolve this? I am using Gradle 4.9 (wrapper) and Eclipse Photon (latest).

When I import some other project, I do not seem to have any problem. I am not sure what specific project setting is causing this issue.

```
Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build.
The supplied build action failed with an exception.
```

Cannot get property 'entryAttributes' on null object
org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionFailureException: The supplied build action failed with an exception.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invokeRun(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invoke(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$1.get(DefaultModelProvider.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$3.call(DefaultModelProvider.java:142)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeBuildActionExecuter(DefaultModelProvider.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModels(DefaultModelProvider.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleProjects(DefaultModelProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.fetchEclipseProjects(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'entryAttributes' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
    at build_cl916rqbnt0opn5it03jtja94$_run_closure1$_closure8$_closure9$_closure10.doCall(C:\git\Phaeton\adjudicateRx\build.gradle:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet.execute(MutableActionSet.java:35)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.mergeXmlClasspath(EclipseClasspath.java:327)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.EclipseModelBuilder.populate(EclipseModelBuilder.java:151)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.EclipseModelBuilder.populate(EclipseModelBuilder.java:240)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.EclipseModelBuilder.buildAll(EclipseModelBuilder.java:100)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.EclipseModelBuilder.buildAll(EclipseModelBuilder.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.CompositeModelQuery.collectRootModels(CompositeModelQuery.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.CompositeModelQuery.execute(CompositeModelQuery.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.CompositeModelQuery.execute(CompositeModelQuery.java:24)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.access$000(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$1.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:285)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:273)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:260)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:225)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:138)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:117)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:100)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:88)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Here is my build.gradle file. Any obvious problems? Thanks!

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url <redacted> }
        maven { url <redacted> }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'pmd'


eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                def source = entries.find { it.path.contains('mylibrary.jar') }
                source.entryAttributes['source_encoding'] = 'UTF-8'
            }
        }
    }
}


compileJava.options*.compilerArgs = [
        "-Xlint:serial", "-Xlint:varargs", "-Xlint:cast", "-Xlint:classfile",
        "-Xlint:dep-ann", "-Xlint:divzero", "-Xlint:empty", "-Xlint:finally",
        "-Xlint:overrides", "-Xlint:path", "-Xlint:processing", "-Xlint:static",
        "-Xlint:try", "-Xlint:fallthrough", "-Xlint:rawtypes", "-Xlint:deprecation",
        "-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:-options"
]

compileTestJava.options*.compilerArgs = [
        "-Xlint:serial", "-Xlint:-varargs", "-Xlint:cast", "-Xlint:classfile",
        "-Xlint:dep-ann", "-Xlint:divzero", "-Xlint:empty", "-Xlint:finally",
        "-Xlint:overrides", "-Xlint:path", "-Xlint:processing", "-Xlint:static",
        "-Xlint:try", "-Xlint:-fallthrough", "-Xlint:-rawtypes", "-Xlint:-deprecation",
        "-Xlint:-unchecked", "-Xlint:-options"]

repositories {
    maven { url "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/maven-remote" }
    maven { url "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo" }

    maven { url "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo2" }
    maven { url "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo3"}
}
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

dependencies {
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        all*.exclude module: 'spring-context-support'
    }
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.20'

    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.10.0'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.10.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.5'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformats-text:2.9.5'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.5'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'
    compile 'org.drools:drools-core:7.7.0.Final'
    compile 'org.drools:drools-compiler:7.7.0.Final'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'

    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.7.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.7.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-core', version: '1.7.4'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile group: 'commons-chain', name: 'commons-chain', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-digester3', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.4'

}


springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.mycompany.myproduct.spring.Application"
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9099'
    }
}


test {
    useJUnit {
        excludeCategories 'com.mycompany.test.IntegrationTest'
    }
}


findbugs {
    excludeFilter = file("./config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}
```

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-project-fails-to-load-in-eclipse-photon/27987

Comment: `org.eclipse.buildship` might have issues with `4.9`; maybe try `4.5 +`.

Comment: without the `build.gradle` that crashes it, this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your eclipse executable has a whitespace in it e.g. “eclipse 2”.
Then it might not work.